# Efficiently save the same time for many objects (postgresql and generally)

Tags: django, database, postgresql, memory-efficient

I have a Django project with many objects (each of them has a row in a Postgresql table).
Bulks of objects have the same time value.

I wonder whether it is good to use same a time field for each of the many data objects (although hundreds of them has the same value), or to create a "context" object that will save the time, and to keep for each object a reference to (in the table - the id of) a context object.

Working with ids (rather than times) is faster, although with context objects two queries should be used (one for the context, and the second for data objects with the reference to the context).
Assuming that saving the same time many times is a waste of space (is it?), the second option is better.

I'm not a DB expert, and will be glad to hear which option is better? What else should be considered?

Comment: Did u have a look at `.bulk_create()` method? May be this is what u want?

Comment: @Chiefir The question is not about the creation procedure, but about two different way to represent data in DB.

Comment: So may be its better to use a word `store` instead of `save` in the question title? Now it is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, saving same time in each row generally is not a bad idea, because having time in the separate table, will force Django ORM to make lots of JOIN operations which is slower than making queries on a single table.

I don't think that saving a little bit of space worth having inconvenience of dealing with multiple tables.